# How to pass higher order component to React Navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

How to pass HOC to React Navigation? I want to wrap component by `SafeArea`. Below example throws an error:

> Functions are not valid as React child. This may happen if you return Component instead of ...

```
function withSafeArea(component: ComponentType) {
  return function WithSafeArea() {
    return <SafeArea>{component}</SafeArea>
  }
}
```

```
<Stack.Screen
     name={Routes.Introduction}
     component={withSafeArea(Introduction)}
/>
```

//edit
response for @Dreew Rese

code causing error from comment

```
    // imports

    function withSafeArea(component: ComponentType) {
      return function WithSafeArea() {
        return <SafeArea>{component}</SafeArea>
      }
    }
    
    const Stack = createStackNavigator()
    
    export const Content = () => {
      const { authenticated } = useAuthentication()
    
      if (authenticated) {
        const IntroductionWithSafeArea = withSafeArea(Introduction)
    
        return (
          <AuthorizedContentProvider>
            <WithNavigation>
              <Stack.Screen
                name={Routes.Introduction}
                component={IntroductionWithSafeArea}
              />
              <Stack.Screen name={Routes.Home} component={Home} />
              <Stack.Screen name={Routes.NewEvent} component={NewEvent} />
            </WithNavigation>
          </AuthorizedContentProvider>
        )
      }
    
      return (
        <WithNavigation>
          <Stack.Screen name={Routes.Sign} component={Sign} />
        </WithNavigation>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This likely is because higher order components *are* really just higher order functions. They just happen to consume React components and return decorated React components. Logically what you've done makes sense, but from React's perspective `withSafeArea` isn't a valid React component.

For these situations you usually will decorate the component when it is exported. Something like:

```
export default withSafeArea(Introduction)
```

But occasionally you need to decorate components "on-the-fly", like when mapping dynamic content. Here you will need to instantiate a wrapped/decorated component just ahead of returning the JSX:

```
const IntroductionWithSafeArea = withSafeArea(Introduction);
...
<Stack.Screen
  name={Routes.Introduction}
  component={IntroductionWithSafeArea}
/>
```

Additionally, you may want to tweak your HOC so it functions a bit more correctly, namely, you want any props passed to it to be passed on to the wrapped component.

```
function withSafeArea(Component: ComponentType) {
  return function WithSafeArea(props) { // <-- accept props
    return (
      <SafeArea>
        <Component {...props} /> // <-- pass props on
      </SafeArea>
    );
  }
}
```

Slightly more succinct

```
const withSafeArea = (Component: ComponentType) => props => (
  <SafeArea>
    <Component {...props} />
  </SafeArea>
)
```

Comment: I receive an error `index.js:1 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

Comment: @Sheppard25 Are you trying to render the HOC directly? Can you show the code causing that warning?

Comment: yes, I edited my first post, please check it out

Comment: @Sheppard25 You are not really implementing your HOC correctly, you are simply passing a component through, so if you keep your HOC as-is then you need to pass an instantiated component, i.e. `withSafeArea(<Introduction />)`.

Comment: but I did like you did but without props :D

Comment: @Sheppard25 Sorry, I was referring to the fact that `{component}` isn't the same as `<Component />` in the HOC. The warning is saying you passed a reference to a React component, not an instantiated one.